# How can I add column at the end of html table on the fly using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add a column at the end of an html table on the fly using jQuery.

I created the following HTML table.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="reportColumns">

    <thead>
        <tr></tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Then I added the following JQuery code

```
 $('.checkbox').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('data-tag');

        $( "#reportColumns > thead > tr" ).append('<th id="'+ id +'">Some Column header</th>');

        $( "#reportColumns > tbody > tr" ).append('<td>-</td>');
 });
```

But for some reason this is not working. No column are being added to the table. Not even the table is visible.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: With this score and these badges, you can't make a minimal effort to properly format your question?? Or post a MCVE??

Comment: Are you sure the .checkbox listener is being fired?

Comment: @Sergeon yes it is. I even logged it to the console

Comment: i just tried and it worked https://jsfiddle.net/kct0ek06/

Comment: For me it's working fine. You probably have an error.
Make a fiddle for your question.

Comment: yes and in the jsfiddle that i have give in my answer it is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kct0ek06/)

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped"     id="reportColumns">

        <thead>
            <tr>fasdfsa</tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>afsdfa</tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
    <div class="checkbox">Click me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#reportColumns thead tr").append('<th id="'+ id +'">Some Column header</th>')
  $("#reportColumns tbody tr").append('<td>-</td>')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sajjansarkar/v9gvjxjz/3/